# Writing declaration file for module that only exports a string-map

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a non-typescript module that basically only exports a simple object mapping strings to other strings or null, e.g. more or less:

```
export = {"foo": "FOO", "bar": null };
```

I try to write a declaration file for that module, and came up with this working solution:

```
declare const x: { [key: string]: string | null | undefined };
export = x;
```

However, is there a better way without introducing a fake variable `x`?